# Como publicar um pacote no NPM com CLI customizada

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, packages, integração-contínua

Eu criei um estrutura de pastas desenvolvida para projeto em NodeJS, porém gostaria de publica-la no NPM com uma CLI customizada, de forma que fosse possível escolher o que se deseja instalar, algo como: `myPackageName --beta=server` onde isto iria instalar apenas a pasta server, ou `myPackageName --beta=webdevelopment` onde isto iria instalar apenas a pasta webdevelopment.

No caso esse myPackageName estaria disponivel após a instalação do projeto principal via npm.

Comment: Esse instalador está em que linguagem? node? bash? outra?

Comment: Seria em NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

Nestes casos o que se faz é publicar um pacote com o nome do produto, mas com uma camada externa que é o próprio instalador. Ou seja, quando se fizer download do pacote ele não dá para usar, só depois de correr o `myPackageName --beta=server`. E nesse caso o melhor seria dar-lhe outro nome.

Isso implica que tenhas um programa `instalador.js` onde podes ler os argumentos passados ao script `deploy` (podes claro mudar este nome). Esse ficheiro teria algo como:

```
const args = process.argv;
const envVariables = args
  .slice(2)
  .join("")
  .split("--")
  .filter(Boolean)
  .reduce((vars, envVar) => {
    const [key, value] = envVar.split("=");
    return { ...vars, [key]: value };
  }, {});

console.log(envVariables);
```

Com esse código poderias usar por exemplo:

```
node instalador --beta=server --lang=en
```

e dentro do ficheiro isso retornaria:

```
{ beta: 'server', lang: 'en' }
```

Ou seja: podes continuar e acrescentar a esse código o resto da lógica sabendo que `envVariables.beta` tem o valor que procuras.